# Do we need to increase activity version in SWF for increasing its timeout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

We have an existing workflow where we need to increase timeout for an activity (Start to Close) to enable an urgent processing. Do we require to do a version bump up on activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you specify the timeout. If you specify it on registration then you have to change the version as registration is immutable. If you specify it as part of the invocation then no need for a new version.

If you are using AWS Flow Framework for Java use [ActivitySchedulingOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/ActivitySchedulingOptions.html) to pass the timeout. Here is the relevant [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/clients.html#schedulingoptions).

Comment: We are setting time out with activity registration, how to specify timeout as part of invocation ?